# How to find the position information I want in an array? (.lua)

Tags: lua

I have a code below and I need to find the information based on the position of each array.

```
local arrayVoc = {
    [1] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    [2] = {6, 7, 8, 9, 10},
    [3] = {11, 12, 13, 14, 15},
    [4] = {16, 17, 18, 19, 20},
    [5] = {21, 22, 23, 24, 25},
    [6] = {26, 27, 28, 29, 30}
}
```

For example: I need to get the information that is in [2] and position 3. Would the result be 8 or 9? If it starts with 0 it would be 9, but if it starts with 1 then it is 8.

How do I build the formula to find the value of the position I want?

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

By default, lua table indices start from `1`. So `arr[2][3]` would yield `8`.

```
arr = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
}

= arr[2][3]
8
```

Comment: Hi, the command to identify and print the result I need is: arr[2][3] ?
Or in my case: arrayVoc[2][3] ?

Comment: I have a error here: `for _, v in pairs(arrayVoc) do
    if type(v) == 'table' then
        if isInArray(v, 8) then
            arrayVoc[v][1]
        end
    end
end`